# swift 4 Date from from ISO string to custom format?

Tags: swift, date

I have ISO date from API I want to convert it to another custom date format, I've checked some threads here it's look like I have to use the extension on Date class, unfortunately, all my attempts failed.

this example for date i have :

```
2014-10-22T00:00:00+00:00
```

I want to convert it to `July 2014`

can I use normal Date class to do it?

and below what I am trying to do

```
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
let date = formatter.date(from: "2016-08-26T12:39:00Z")
let string = formatter.string(from: Date())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it:

```
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
if let date = formatter.date(from: "2014-10-22T00:00:00+00:00") {
    let string = date.stringDate
    print(string) // October 2014
}

extension Date {

    var stringDate: String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy"
        return formatter.string(from: self)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

my Date load from SQL Server and format like this "2018-01-17T03:08:28.158769" the code below is work for me perfectly

```
let isoDate = "2018-01-17T03:08:28.158769"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from:isoDate!)!
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d.MMMM.YYYY"
let displayDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
displayDateInLabel.text = displayDate
```

result 
17.January.2018

Answer (score 0):

You can get Month and Year like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(getFormattedDate(date: Date()))

}

func getFormattedDate(date: Date) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM YYYY"
    let strMonth = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    return strMonth
}
```